# Update records from Linked table

Tags: sql, t-sql

How to update records in a Existing table.

I have two tables studentinfo , studentrecords

> Table : Student info:

```
HTID  Class   BadgeID  Location  Begindate
133   T1      .##       NJ      2018-01-31
```

I updated BadgeID to .### in studentinfo table.

> Student records table contain

```
ID      Badge       Location    Name      Date
133   02311.01       NJ        Steve     2018-01-31
```

How can i update the Student records table.

> Result should be:

```
ID      Badge       Location    Name      Date
133   02311.001       NJ        Steve     2018-01-31
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't.  You should remove `badgeId` from one of the tables, and use a `JOIN` to fetch it when you need it.

Repeating data in different tables is a really bad idea in a relational database.  It just introduces opportunities for incompatibilities and confusion.

Answer (score 0):

use join

```
update  s
set s.badge=r.badge
from 
Studentinfo  s join StudentR r on s.HTID =r.id
```

but it seems you need select query from output

```
select s.TID,r.Badge,s.Location,r.Name, 
,r.Date from  Studentinfo  s join StudentR r on s.HTID =r.id
```

Comment: @Jennifer i have write both query

Comment: @Jennifer what is the two table name

Comment: @Jennifer https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=86c6f70f22cbb63047ab97a1fce52960 here demo of fiddle check it and correct your code

Comment: @Jennifer fiddle link have you checked that